# Enable marking posts as answered on a different site? It seems like a good idea to me

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, self-answer

Recently I asked a question on Stack Overflow, but then found an answer on Computer Science Stack Exchange, so I posted a link in a comment (I would have felt bad answering my own question with a link to someone else's answer!) because it added value to the site. I would have liked to have a way to mark the question as answered even though nobody had posted an answer to the question.

I would like to discuss the idea of some feature along these lines.

Comment: As someone who has encountered the exact same situation, and *almost* asked this question last month, I'll give you +1 :) *(by the way, I ended up doing what Journeyman Geek suggested)*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Recently I asked a question on stack overflow, but then found an answer on computer science stack exchange

While copying the answer verbatim isn't right, there's nothing stopping you from referencing that answer, and giving credit to the poster and posting your own answer explaining *how* that helped you resolve the issue. Maybe drop a comment to OP mentioning this.

While a link only answer is bad there's often value in talking about not just the *what* but how it was applicable to your own specific situation. Also by writing a more fleshed out answer that references the other, you improve folks ability to find solutions in both your question/answer pair, *and* it'd act as a signpost to the answer that helped you.

Marking a question as resolved *without* an answer, even as a comment can have issues for us. What if the other answer is deleted, and we lose the wisdom of the ancients.

[image]
<sub>[Link to XKCD](https://xkcd.com/979/)</sub>

Comment: Additionally, comments can be deleted anytime without a trace.

Comment: That too - but that even involves finding the question first. I'm not sure comments are going to be picked up by a search engine as effectively as an answer